# Question about powerset exercise in book of proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm self studying this book: [http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/](http://www.people.vcu.edu/%7Erhammack/BookOfProof/)

My background is cal1,2,3, ODEs. I mainly want to learn how to prove.

Section 1.4 Ex 10.

We know that:$\text{ P({1,2,3}) = {$\emptyset$, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}} }$

$\text{10. \{X $\in$ P(\{1,2,3\}) : |X| $\le$ 1 \}}$

This means every element in P such that its cardinality is less than or equal to 1.
Therefore, the answer is: $\text{ {$\emptyset$, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}}}$

Comment: Did you have a question? Your answer is correct.

Comment: "prove" is the verb. Perhaps you want to learn how to *do a* proof, not "how to proof".

Comment: @Malady yeah, I just wanted to verify my answer, sorry I dont know how to post. English is not my 1st language

Comment: Your english is perfectly fine. And so is your proof.

Comment: It's difficult to write any answer beyond "yes you are correct". Did you have any specific doubts on why your answer might have been wrong? Do you have any other questions related to the exercise?

Comment: Yeah pretty much I wanted a solution check because I wasn't sure about the way I was reading the  set notation. that is all. I guess this is not the place to do that (?). To answer your last question: not anymore, I could post other questions for solution check but again I don't think this is the place for that. Plus, after this I'm more confident my reasoning and the answers are correct. I'll go back later on and actually prove some results with more rigor when I actually get good at writing proofs. Cheers